# Getting PHP to work with apache to run .php files through browser

Tags: php, apache-2.2

I have VPS running Debian 5.0 (I think) and I would like to get it to run PHP files. I was told it needed to be configured with Apache. I tried entering the command `apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5`. But there was no change. Console output: http://pastebin.com/sVMWq6mA

This is everything in my `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`:
`http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/6474/modsb.jpg`

My webserver can be accessed here:
http://206.217.223.136/test/
In my test.php file I have the code :

```
<?php
 phpinfo();
?>
```

but instead of displaying the page, it tries to download it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried "a2enmod php" or "a2enmod php5" on your console to enable the php module?

Your command line is correct and it seems that everything is installed correct.

Edit: I have looked its

```
a2enmod php5
apache2ctl restart
```

Edit2: Ok i have looked on the server for the problem. There were different problems with the apt-get installer. Then were httpd running on port 80 so apache2 could'nt start on the port and the test.php file was not in a correct file encoding this was the main problem. After checking all of them and create a new file with vi it was running.

Comment: `ERROR: Module php does not exist!`

Comment: And have you tried "php5" ? Edit: With witch user do you try this? And you can look to the mods-available folder. There are all available modules and you can look for the name.

Comment: a2enmod php5 also says module does not exist. I'm using the root user for this.

Comment: Ok another way go to /etc/apache2/mods-available is there a module called php? oder php5? @Kevin Duke

Comment: I have installed before a few minutes a the same problem. But i have made a new apt-get install php5 and then restart the apache with apache2ctl restart. Then it was working. And under mods-avalable must be an mod php5.conf and php5.load

Comment: nothing seems to be working... could we try teamviewer?

Comment: lol I'm usually up late so it shouldn't be a problem ;) However, I get an "Unknown user error" when adding deatmaster@web.de on MSN. You can try adding me dukevinjduke@gmail.com. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate this!

Comment: @stony lol I restarted apache2 with `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload` and php doesn't work again. Would you mind taking a look again? Thanks :)

Comment: @Stony Ah, I guess you aren't online, when you get back, if you don't want to connect, could you please tell me what to do to fix it again? Thank you!

Comment: I am on write me @Kevin Duke

Comment: @Stony it keeps saying you're offline and when I send you a message it says "Cannot send" :/ I'm always online so if you can, please write to me

Comment: I looks that MSN has some trouble. I write you @Kevin Duke

Comment: @stony I'm online right now. When I try to view your information in MSN, it says "Error retrieving profile. The user most likely does not exist." Ah stupid MSN or maybe stupid US government haha

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
apache2ctl graceful
```

EDIT: some explaining

Installing just the php5 package does not give Apache any modules. Installing the libapache2-mod-php5 package installs the php5 module to Apache and should enable it by default.

Comment: vps:~# apache2ctl graceful
httpd not running, trying to start
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs

Answer (score 0):

Check your httpd.conf file and ensure you have a line like this:

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`

Also ensure that you have loaded your php module:

`LoadModule php5_module        *path to your php module*/libphp5.so`

This is the way I have configured it on my web servers.

Comment: command LoadModule not found :/ and what directory can I find the httpd.conf

Comment: LoadModule is not a command. You have to write this into your httpd. config in debian this should be under /etc/apache2/

Comment: @Stony Do I put both of these in httpd.conf? Right now the file is blank.

Comment: It still doesn't work by adding these

Comment: When you install php5 over the apt-get function he load automaticly the php module. When you write this in your canfig you should look to your errorlog if the module is loaded 2 times.

Comment: I'm not sure what was confusing about my response and warranted downvoting. The response was correct for a vanilla install of apache. If you add the lines that i suggested to the httpd.conf file you could have loaded the php module and told the server what to do with .php files.